# It's possible to ctx.drawImage svg on Mousemove with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, canvas, drawimage

I'm **trying** to have a svg that follows the mouse, I'm trying to use .drawImage to get what I want, but I don't understand why the 'var img = new Image ();' is an incorrect variable, where is the error? **If** instead of the new image variable, I use ctx.createRadialGradient,  I get what I want, but with the image no, I'm new on javascript so tips and criticisms are appreciated! :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var canvasW = window.innerWidth;
    var canvasH = window.innerHeight;
     ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
        img.src = "https://svgshare.com/i/LDY.sfsvg";
       
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvasW,canvasH);

  });
  });
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas >
  
</canvas>
```

Comment: Besides the comma typo, you are creating and loading a new image at every mousemove event. Don't! Create it once, and in the mousemove event only draw that image.

Comment: @Kaiido Ok got it, excuse my nooby questions, so I've update the snippet, i've put the semicolon and delete the onload function, so now, the drawImg its drawn only for the first mousemove event , right? so now in this code, it's everything fine, but i don't get it where the img Coordinates are, ok its drawn only one time, but how do I assign its position to the mousemove? Also I don't need anymore the "canvas.height and canvas,width" or im wrong?

Comment: Editing your question after it received an answer is not very well received here. Also, we can't lead you step by steps. What you are trying to do is very basic and has been covered hundreds of times in various tutorials about drawing on canvas. + I never said to remove the onload event handler, you need it. You are still creating a new Image per mousemove. What do you think `0, 0` does in `drawImage(img, 0, 0 ...`?

Comment: Got it, I have no idea what 0, 0 is needed, I'm going to study the basics, thanks also for telling me not to edit the questions, it makes sense. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem is that you are missing a semicolon after the declaration of ctx

```js
    var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
     ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
        img.src = "https://svgshare.com/i/LDY.sfsvg";
```

Another one is that you never define these variables
**canvasW, canvasH**

Comment: Thank you, I've Update the Snippet Code, let' s check it !  I am starting to understand the functions of java, I am self-taught and not a native English speaker so thank you for your time!